# How to prepopulate the currency of a commerce_price field

Tags: commerce

I want to prepopulate the currency (select list of available currencies) of a commerce_price field.

(edit – specify my question):

I don't want to prepopulate any value (e.g. EUR) for my field as a default value for all new content. I need to have different currency values prepopulated through content-create links out of different views.

Example (I know the syntax doesn't work, that's my problem):

1st Link: http://www.example.com/node/add/contenttype?[curreny-value]=USD

2nd Link: http://www.example.com/node/add/contenttype?edit[title]=EUR

The curreny value should be visible but disabled (not editable) in any prepopulated forms.

Is that possible with the prepopulate module or do I need a hook?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Commerce Multi Currency](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module.

> This module enhances some of the multi-currency capabilities of Drupal
>   Commerce.
>
> Current features:
>
> UI for fine granular definition of exchange rates. (Every currency
>   combination can be defined separately if needed) Synchronization of
>   currency exchange rates directly from the European Central Bank (ECB).
>   UI to specify which rates shall be synchronized and which are handled
>   manually. Generation of currency specific price fields inclusive
>   generation of rule-set to handle them. hooks for easy integration of
>   custom currency exchange rate sources.

This will give you a 'Price with currency' widget for your field.

And you will have a dropdown with all active currencies next to the price.
[image]

Comment: ok, thanks, that looks interesting. I also take into account to use mvf with units for that. But I think, the module I choose doesn't solve my problem with the prepopulation of the currency.
Above I specified my question.